# Ubuntu 16.04 does not install. (There is only the ubuntu start screen but no installation)

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi

I want to install Ubuntu 16.04. 
[The boot menu pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7w2d.png), but after choosing "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu", there is only the [Ubuntu splash screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9oOl.jpg), which seems to be loading, and stops.

After this, nothing moves. There is only the Ubuntu Screen but no Desktop or Installation Process.

Only command line opens.

What can I do to install Ubuntu 16.04 properly on UEFI (PC model: ASUS GL522 V)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried holding down `F6` during a cold boot, select language, then `F6` again to get the options on the lower right to show up. Select `nolapic`, `EDD=On`, and `nomodeset`. Press ENTER. Next, down arrow to the second line which is the Install line. **DO NOT PRESS ENTER OR A LEFT OR RIGHT ARROW!!** Now back space and delete quiet and splash with `nomodeset`. Now press ENTER. The installation will begin and if it hangs up now, you will see what was the last process/script that completed.

You should go to the grub, where you choose the booting operating system. If it doesn't appear by default, you should press shift until you see it. Then choose the Ubuntu, or Install Ubuntu (it depends, you will see it hopefully), go to it with the arrows and press the 'e' key. Here go to the line which contains "quiet splash" at the end and add "acpi=off" after these words. Then press F10 to boot with these settings. you should be aware of that it changes only for the initial boot, after it, when you want to install Linux, you need to change it again.

Comment: I've tried but it does not work. Is ther no way to use the command line to boot?

Comment: are you installing from usb??

Comment: no. It is a new computer with windows 10 preinstalled. It's not the first time I  installed a new operating system, but I don't understand why it does not work. Is it possible, that windows stopps ubuntu from installing or could it be the model which is not compatible with ubuntu?

Comment: Sorry I missunderstand your question. Yes I boot from an USB

Comment: i changed my answer check it

Answer (score 0):

you were able to boot to the grub means the problem probably is from damage bootable disk creation process.

Since you are on UEFI, i prefer you make an EFI exclusive bootable disk.When you are using windows, use rufus and choose **GPT for UEFI** as target filesytem and **FAT32** .

after burning Wait for the light to stop blinking before removing drive

Comment: It does not work. Don't understand why.